# How to check CAPTCHA in controller?

Tags: php, yii

I need to check CAPTCHA in controller so I should get CAPTCHA session value from session table.  I check session table and i see something like this:

```
Yii.CCaptchaAction.3bbe352e.controllername.captcha|s:7:"xemobin"
```

What is this "3bbe352e"?

Is this value constant?

Can i check CAPTCHA session in controller like this?

```
if ($session['Yii.CCaptchaAction.3bbe352e.controllername.captcha']==$_POST['captcha'])
```

Comment: Take time to visit all the sections of the FAQ. It may helps you to foster your Stackoverflow experience.

Answer (score 6):

### FORM

add the captcha widget to the form

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?><br>
<?php echo CHtml::textField('captcha'); ?>
```

### CONTROLLER

add captcha to controller actions

```
public function actions()   {
    return array(
    // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
    'captcha'=>array(
       'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
       'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
    ));
}
```

### CONTROLLER ACTION

then in your controller action

```
$captcha=Yii::app()->getController()->createAction("captcha");
$code = $captcha->verifyCode;
if($code === $_REQUEST['captcha']){...}
```

Comment: FORM should have been rendered by CONTROLLER and CONTROLLER ACTION should also be inside the same CONTROLLER. Above `$captcha=Yii::app()->getController()->createAction("captcha");` can be written as `$this->createAction('captcha');`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function rules()
{
   return array(
      array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'on'=>'captchaRequired'),
   );
}
```

the below line add in controller

```
$model = new LoginForm;
// if a user already tried to login, then set a scenario:
$model->scenario = 'captchaRequired';
```